# IOException when writing byte array

Tags: java, file-io, nio, ioexception

I am getting `IOException: Map Failed` when trying to write a large byte array. I use the method below to write a byte array to a file

```
private static void write(byte[] data) throws Exception {
        File file = new File("C:/temp/file.json");
        int length = data.length;
        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
        FileChannel fc = raf.getChannel();
        MappedByteBuffer buffer = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, length);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            buffer.put(data[i]);
        }
}
```

The byte array is about 270mb. 
Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong? 
Thanks.

Comment: can you add the stack trace? also your jdk version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure why the map failed, but I wouldn't do it the way you have done.

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
out.write(data);
out.close();
```

to do it progressively you can use

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i += 8192)
    out.write(data, i, Math.min(data.length-i, 8192));
out.close();
```

The map could fail if you have a 32-bit JVM and you call this method repeatedly. e.g. you run out of virtual memory.

Comment: ok, so tried that instead and I get an OutOfMemoryError, but I have set -Xmx1024m

Comment: Where do you get the OOME? Is it in this code or somewhere else? I suspect the problem is when you generate the very large `byte[]` If that is the case I suggest writing to the file as you generate the String rather than making several copies in memory.

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:269)`

Comment: Hmmmm, You can write the data in blocks or increase the heap size, but the real solution is to write the data as it is generated and not build the `byte[]` at all. I assume you are not using a 32-bit JVM?

Comment: Agreed. I guess we're slightly off topic now from the original question. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Added an example of how to write 8 KB at a time.

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution is the same than in C with the `mmap()` function. If you just created the file, you should seek in it to `data.length-1` offset and write a byte at this position in order to  have a file of that size before mapping it. When I don't do it in C, I get memory corruption while accessing mapped memory.

Something like that should work :

```
private static void write(byte[] data) throws Exception {
        File file = new File("C:/temp/file.json");
        int length = data.length;
        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");

        FileChannel fc = raf.getChannel();
        fc.position(size-1);
        ByteBuffer bf = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[]{0x00});

        bf.flip();  // Not sure if flip is needed !!!!!!!

        fc.write(bf);

        MappedByteBuffer buffer = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, length);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            buffer.put(data[i]);
        }
}
```

To make simple : You can't map more than the file size, that's why you need to increase the file size before mapping it.

This can explain your problem, but I think it's more appropriate to open a `FileOutputStream` and directly write your data in it. You can still map it after if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Is your JVM max heap size at least 270*2 MB? You would set this on the command line used to start Java:

java ... -Xmx 1024m ...

Comment: But `MappedByteBuffer` uses off-heap memory?

Comment: I see a lot of "may reside" in the javadoc, but it is definitely a possibility the doc points out. Is there another reference you are consulting?

Comment: No, I'm speaking from general knowledge---the point of the memory-mapped buffer is that it transparently uses natively allocated memory, which is the only way to avoid heap-to-native memcpy before actually flushing the buffer to the file. Of course, it may possibly turn out that the native buffer is itself on the heap, but that doesn't seem reasonable to me.

Comment: I suspect you are right. In either case, I think @PeterLawrey has the more relevant answer. The OP may not even want memory mapped IO.

Comment: Yes, a clean, straightforward, three-line solution, and speed is not compromised, either.